# Sql: Aggregate Function: How to get row number column for table given in example

Tags: sql-server

I have a temporary table generated like below,

```
CarName CarNumber   Count   DiscountedPrice
Ford    C296A23E1   3       5715.13
Ford    C296A23E2   3       5715.13
Ford    C296A23E3   3       5715.13
BMW     311426001   5       1999
BMW     311426002   5       1999
BMW     311426003   5       1999
BMW     311426004   5       1999
BMW     311426005   5       1999
Honda   426000021   4       0
Honda   426000022   4       0
Honda   426000023   4       0
Honda   426000024   4       0
```

Above table is due to querying few tables.

i would like to have additional column (Rown Number) to this temporary table like below

```
RowNumber   CarName CarNumber   Count   DiscountedPrice
1           Ford    C296A23E1   3   5715.13
1           Ford    C296A23E2   3   5715.13
1           Ford    C296A23E3   3   5715.13
2           BMW     311426001   5   1999
2           BMW     311426002   5   1999
2           BMW     311426003   5   1999
2           BMW     311426004   5   1999
2           BMW     311426005   5   1999
3           Honda   426000021   4   0
3           Honda   426000022   4   0
3           Honda   426000023   4   0
3           Honda   426000024   4   0
```

Basically i don't want just row number, which i would be able to get using ROW_NUMBER() function but i want no for CarName and that to be repeated for all the row that belong to a specific car.

any idea how to do it?

Comment: Just use dense_rank()?

Comment: so thats the difference between a novice and experts :) I was breaking my head over this since morning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `DENSE_RANK`. The following example sort the manufacturer alphabetically:

```
SELECT *, RowNumber = DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY CarName)
FROM table_name
```

Answer (score 1):

Use DENSE_RANK:

```
DENSE_RANK() over(order by Carname)
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ms173825%28v=SQL.120%29.aspx